# Notification when a new message is sent

Tags: java, android, firebase

i have tried to make a notification when a user send a new message and is not in the chat. The app should only send notifications if the user is not in the current chat. I watched some YouTube tutorials but non of them worked for me.

My chat has following structure if its relevant:

```
/users/
    - $userId/
        + deviceId
        + username
        + email
        + uid
        + joined
        - conversations/
            - $userId/
                + conversationId

/conversations/
    - $conversationId/
        - members/
            + userId1
            + userId2
        - messages/
            - $messageId/
                + messageId
                + content
                + timestamp
                + type
```

My source code is on github
https://github.com/ARCOOON/UpChat

Comment: Without any code what so ever it's rather hard trying to help you. Take a look at [ask]

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: i mean, if a user sends a message and the app is in background or in the conversation, it should send a notification